# Chartjs not showing up in Foundation5 Tabs

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, chart.js

I'm using Chartjs with Foundation I have three charts that I want to be displayed on three tabs.

The chart only shows in the first tab. How can I get it to show in the second and third tabs? Can someone demonstrate a solution with a JSFiddle?

HTML:

```
<ul id="view-tabs" class="row tabs" data-tab>
    <li class="tab-title active small-12 medium-4 day"><a href="#day">View Day</a></li>
    <li class="tab-title small-12 medium-4 week"><a href="#week">View Week</a></li>
    <li class="tab-title small-12 medium-4 month"><a href="#month">View Month</a></li>
</ul> 

<div class="tabs-content">
    <div class="content day-data active" id="day">
        <canvas id="day-graph" width="300" height="300"></canvas> 
    </div>
    <div class="content week-data" id="week">
        <canvas id="week-graph" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="content month-data id="month">
        <canvas id="month-graph" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Chartjs js
- this script just shows the `#day-graph` but it won't show if I place it in the 2nd or 3rd tab.

```
var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};
  var lineChartData = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets : [
      {
        label: "Visitors",
        fillColor : "rgba(148,194,116, 0.5)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
      }
    ]

  }

window.onload = function(){
  var ctx = document.getElementById("day-graph").getContext("2d");
  window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
    responsive: true
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As u can see, u're executing new instance of Chart within window.onload function. This is the first reason.

Take a closer look - at the execution:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("day-graph").getContext("2d");
```

You took the context over one canvas object, but in tabs you have three views. Sciprt cannot figure out that it should exec other charts.

U need to repeat the approach 3 times - the number of charts inside the tabs, for example:

```
//some previous code    
var ctx = document.getElementById("week-graph").getContext("2d");
      window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
        responsive: true
      });
```

But for the optimalization purposes u should execucute the instance IF the tab in currently avaiable. And this thing u should do by yourself.

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tabs.html#callbacks